# How do I pop off the first array element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm iterating through an array of json data but need to remove the first element prior to the iteration. How do I remove the initial element?  This is what I have so far:

```
    $.post('player_data.php', {method: 'getplayers', params: $('#players_search_form').serialize()}, function(data) {

        if (data.success) {

           // How do I remove the first element ?

            $.each(data.urls, function() {
                ...
            });
        }

    }, "json");
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Plain javascript will do:

```
data.urls.shift()
```

On [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) method:

> Removes the first element from an array and returns that element. This
>   method changes the length of the array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Answer (score 2):

There's a method like pop, but from the front instead

```
data.urls.shift()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Answer (score 2):

If `data.url` is just an array, the simplest way to solve this problem is to use the Javascript's [splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) function:

```
if (data.success) {
  //remove the first element from the urls array
  data.urls.splice(0,1);
  $.each(data.urls, function() {
     ...
```

You can also use [shift()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp) if you need the value of the first url:

```
if (data.success) {
  //remove the first element from the urls array
  var firstUrl = data.urls.shift();
  //use the value of firstUrl
  ...
  $.each(data.urls, function() {
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.shift()
```

It will remove the first element from the array

In your case it is

```
data.urls.shift()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `shift()` function from the Array class, which removes (and returns - though you can just discard it) the first element from the array. Take a look at the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) for more information.

```
data.urls.shift();
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can remove the first element of an array by using [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift):

```
// your array
data.urls;

// remove first element
var firstElem = data.urls.shift();

// do something with the rest
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first item of an array in javascript (it will also work if you're using jquery) use `data.urls.shift()`. This will also return the first item, but you can ignore the return value if you don't want to use it. For more info, see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp.